# [Solved]GO annotations do not work.screen does not show anything under {{.User.name}}

Tags: html, go

I want to use go's objx package to get the UserName of the cookie and pass it to html using annotations, but the screen does not show anything under {{.User.name}}.

```
--callback--
authCookieValue := objx.New(map[string]interface{}{
            "name": user.Name(),
        }).MustBase64()
        http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
            Name: "auth",
            Value: authCookieValue,
            Path: "/"})
        log.Printf("user.name",user.Name())
        w.Header()["Location"]=[]string{"/chat"}
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
```

```
--serveHTTP--
func (t *templateHandler)  ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
....
    data := map[string]interface{}{
    "Host": r.Host,
    }
    if authCookie, err := r.Cookie("auth"); err == nil {
        log.Printf("authCookie",authCookie)
        data["UserData"] = objx.MustFromBase64(authCookie.Value)
    }
t.templ.Execute(w,r)
```

```
--html--
    <form id="chatbox">
        {{.UserData.name}}:<br/>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="送信"/>
    </form>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSog6.png)
[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnAbF.png)
Please help us.

I was able to confirm that the authCookie and userName were obtained by planting a log.

```
2023/06/19 09:16:20 authCookie%!(EXTRA *http.Cookie=auth=eyJuYW1lIjoiZ2F0ZSBnYXRlIn0=)
2023/06/19 09:16:26 user.name%!(EXTRA string=gate gate)
2023/06/19 09:16:26 authCookie%!(EXTRA *http.Cookie=auth=eyJuYW1lIjoiZ2F0ZSBnYXRlIn0=)
```

[Problem solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmpvt.png)

Comment: Guess is that this is because `name` is not exported (`{{.UserData.name}}` should be `{{.UserData.Name}}`). Putting this into a runnable example ([for example](https://go.dev/play/p/ijoSmLNzXCi)) makes it easier to trace.

Comment: [This demo](https://go.dev/play/p/t9sa8AVJOGF) is based on @Brits's. And it works.

Comment: @ZekeLu - I had assumed `UserData` was a `struct` but, as your demo shows, it's a `map` so my comment is probably irrelevant (but will leave it there as a starting point).

Comment: can you also paste the code that actually calls the rendering function ?

Comment: @ZekeLu cc: @Brits @LeGEC Thanks to you the problem is solved.
The problem was caused by not excuting the mapped data.
`// t.templ.Execute(w, r)`
 `t.templ.Execute(w, data)`